# Move files from one directory to another with Paramiko

Tags: python, linux, ssh, sftp, paramiko

I have a script that creates and tmp directory on an SFTP server and then puts files in said `/tmp` once the transfer is complete however I need to move the files from `/tmp` back one directory to root `/`. Use Paramiko how would I move the files from one remote directory to another?

Step guide:

> Local files -----> Remote Temporary Dir ----> Remote root Dir

Code below if needed:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# --------------------------------------------------------------------
#import libraries
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
import paramiko as PM
import os
import datetime

# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# Global Variables
# --------------------------------------------------------------------

host = 'host IP address'
port = 22
username = 'Username'
password = '*********'

# Variable Paths

localPath = '/shares/MILKLINK/fromML'
remotePath = '/'
logPath = '/shares/MILKLINK/logs/PPcfg02.log'
SRCfiles = '/shares/MILKLINK/Milklink.cpy'

# --------------------------------------------------------------------
#  Create LOG FILE
# --------------------------------------------------------------------

log = open(logPath, 'a')
log.write(datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()+'\n')

# Creating lockfile

if(os.path.isfile('LockSFTP')):
    log.write("LOCK FILE STILL EXISTS!")
    quit()
else:    
    os.system(">LockSFTP")

# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# Remove all files from /formML/ 
# --------------------------------------------------------------------

fileList = os.listdir(localPath)
for fileName in fileList:
    try:
        os.remove(localPath+"/"+fileName)
    except OSError:
        log.write("%s could not be deleted\n" % fileName)

# --------------------------------------------------------------------
#  Create SFTP CONNECTION
# --------------------------------------------------------------------

log.write("Starting Connection...\n")
# SSH connection
ssh_Connection = PM.Transport((host, port))
ssh_Connection.connect(username = username, password = password)

# Creaat SFTP CLIENT SERVICES
sftp = PM.SFTPClient.from_transport(ssh_Connection) 

log.write("Connection Established...\n")

remoteList = sftp.listdir(remotePath)
fileList = os.listdir(SRCfiles)
try:
    sftp.chdir(remotePath+'/tmp')
except IOError:
    sftp.mkdir(remotePath+'/tmp')
    sftp.chdir(remotePath+'/tmp')

for fileName in fileList:
    if 'comphaulier.asc' not in remoteList:
        if 'Last' in fileName:
            continue
        else:
            sftp.put(SRCfiles+'/'+fileName, remotePath+'/tmp/'+fileName)

        log.write(fileName+" Transferred\n")
    else:
        log.write("Files Still Exist\n")
        log.close()
        quit()

checkList = sftp.listdir(remotePath)

if len(checkList) == 7:
    sftp.put(SRCfiles+'/LastFile.lst', remotePath+'/LastFile.lst')
    log.write("LastFile.lst Transferred\n")
else:
    log.write("Not all files transferred!!!\n")
    quit()

sftp.close()
ssh_Connection.close()

os.system("rm LockSFTP")
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use the [`sftp.rename`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.rename):

```
sftp.rename(remotePath+'/tmp/'+fileName, remotePath+fileName)
```

Note that some SFTP servers fail the request, if the source and target directories are on different file systems.

---

If you need to move set of files from one folder to another, see:
[Archive all files from one SFTP folder to another in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62558399/850848)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest having also some safeguards. Sometimes the library will raise an IOError in certain conditions (the destination file exists already or the file to move does not exist). I will assume you have an sftp client `sftp_client`

```
def move_file(self, source, destination):
    destination_file_exists = __file_exists(destination)
    source_file_exists = __file_exists(source)
    if destination_file_exists:
        # handle the condition accordingly
        print(f"destination file {destination} already exists")
    else:
        if source_file_exists:
            sftp_client.rename(source, destination)
        else:
            # handle the condition accordingly
            print(f"source file {source} does not exist")

def __file_exists(file_path):
    try:
        sftp_client.stat(file_path)
        return True
    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        return False
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Answer (score -2):

As you are already importing the os library use:

```
os.path.join(path, filename)
```

To obtain correct absolute paths and avoid dealing with duplicated or lacking / by the use of wild concatenations like above:

i.e.

```
f_w_current_path = os.path.join(current_path, f.filename)
f_w_temporary_path = os.path.join(temporary_path, f.filename)
sftp.rename(f_w_current_path, f_w_temporary_path)
```

the use of rename to move the file remotely with paramiko library it's working for me.

Comment: You cannot use `os.path.join` for SFTP paths. SFTP always uses forward slash for path separator, while `os.path.join` uses path separator of the local system (what would be backslash in Windows). Your code would introduce same problem that pysftp module has: [Python pysftp put_r does not work on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58460718/850848).