# Python pysftp put_r does not work on Windows

Tags: python, upload, sftp, pysftp

I'd like to upload multiple files from a Windows directory to an SFTP server using pysftp 0.2.8.  I've read up the doc and it suggests to use `put_d` or `put_r` but both give me the following error:

> OSError: Invalid path:

```
sftp_local_path = r'C:\Users\Swiss\some\path'

sftp_remote_path = '/FTP/LPS Data/ATC/RAND/20191019_RAND/XML'

with pysftp.Connection("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", username=myUsername, password=myPassword) as sftp:
    with sftp.cd(sftp_remote_path):
        sftp.put_r(sftp_local_path, sftp_remote_path)
        for i in sftp.listdir():
            lstatout=str(sftp.lstat(i)).split()[0]
            if 'd' in lstatout: print (i, 'is a directory')

sftp.close()
```

I'd like to be able to copy all files or selected files from my local directory to the SFTP server.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your exact problem, but indeed the recursive functions of pysftp are known to be implemented in a way that makes them fail on Windows (or any system that does not use *nix-like path syntax).

Pysftp uses `os.sep` and `os.path` functions for remote SFTP paths, what is wrong, as SFTP paths always use a forward slash.

---

But you can easily implement a portable replacement:

```
import os
```

```
def put_r_portable(sftp, localdir, remotedir, preserve_mtime=False):
    for entry in os.listdir(localdir):
        remotepath = remotedir + "/" + entry
        localpath = os.path.join(localdir, entry)
        if not os.path.isfile(localpath):
            try:
                sftp.mkdir(remotepath)
            except OSError:     
                pass
            put_r_portable(sftp, localpath, remotepath, preserve_mtime)
        else:
            sftp.put(localpath, remotepath, preserve_mtime=preserve_mtime)
```

Use it like:

```
put_r_portable(sftp, sftp_local_path, sftp_remote_path, preserve_mtime=False)
```

---

Note that the above code can be easily modified to work with Paramiko directly, in case you do not want to use pysftp. The [Paramiko `SFTPClient` class](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient) also has the [`put`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.put) method. The only difference is that the Paramiko's `put` does not have the `preserve_mtime` parameter/functionality (but it can be implemented easily, if you need it).

---

*For a similar question about `get_r`, see:

[Python pysftp get_r from Linux works fine on Linux but not on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50118919/850848)*

Comment: Thank you for your help ... this is worked.  I still have so much to learn in Python.