# Upload all files from local folder with specific extension to SFTP server using Paramiko

Tags: python, python-3.x, sftp, paramiko

I am using paramiko to upload files to SFTP server. I want to transfer all files in folder. The names of files are in a manner `one.txt`, `two.txt`.... . I want the files to be sent sequentially like `one.txt` then `two.txt` then `three.txt`.....the below code for transfer of one file runs fine, but the last code which I have tried to transfer all files is not working....

```
import paramiko

source = r'/home/netcs/b/one.txt'
dest = r'/home/tein/c/pickle.txt'
hostname = '10.10.10.9'
port = 22 # default port for SSH
username = 'tein'
password = 'po'

try:
    t = paramiko.Transport((hostname, port))
    t.connect(username=username, password=password)
    sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(t)
    sftp.put(source, dest)
finally:
    t.close()
```

Transfer all files (not working):

```
import paramiko

source = r'/home/netcs/b/'
dest = r'/home/tein/c/'
hostname = '10.10.10.9'
port = 22 # default port for SSH
username = 'tein'
password = 'po'
for file in source:
    if file.endswith('.txt'):
       try:
          t = paramiko.Transport((hostname, port))
          t.connect(username=username, password=password)
          sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(t)
          sftp.put(source, dest)
       finally:
          t.close()
       break
    else:
        print('No txt file found')
```

I have files in `b/`:
[image]

But the script's output is:

```
no txt file found
no txt file found
no txt file found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code never reads the local directory. Your `for` loop iterates *characters* in the `'/home/netcs/b/'` *string*, not *files* in the `/home/netcs/b/` *folder*.

- For listing files in a folder, use `os.listdir`:
  [How do I list all files of a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3207219/850848)

  Also the `os.listdir` returns filenames only, so you have to combine them with the `source` when calling `SFTPClient.put`.
- Similarly the `remotepath` argument of `SFTPClient.put` must also be a full file path.
- You do not want to `break` after the first found file
- Other issue is that the `print('No txt file found')` is misplaced. You will print that for *every* file that does not have `.txt` extension.

```
files = os.listdir(source)
for file in files:
    if file.endswith('.txt'):
       try:
          t = paramiko.Transport((hostname, port))
          t.connect(username=username, password=password)
          sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(t)
          sftp.put(os.path.join(source, file), dest + "/" + file)
       finally:
          t.close()
```

---

For a recursive upload, see:
[Python pysftp put_r does not work on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58460718/850848)