# Unzip files on an SFTP server using Python

Tags: python, zip, sftp, paramiko

I have a zip file which is present on an SFTP server. I am writing a AWS lambda function and have Paramiko module to connect to the SFTP server. I have written below code to unzip the file and code is getting executed successfully but the file is not getting unzipped. Can some one please help where I am going wrong or an alternate way to unzip the file on server?

```
to_sftp.chdir('<dir name>')
flo =  BytesIO()
to_sftp.getfo('<dir name/filename.zip', flo)
flo.seek(0)
root = z.ZipFile(flo,'w')
print(root)
root.extractall(to_sftp.chdir('<dir name'))
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no way the [`ZipFile.extractall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extractall) can write the files directly to the SFTP server. You have to extract the files to a local temporary folder. And then [upload them one-by-one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68180157/850848).

AWS Lambda seems to have a temporary folder in `/tmp`, just like regular *nix server. See [Can I store a temp file on AWS Lambda Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50946378/850848)

---

Other option is to explicitly iterate all files in the ZIP archive using [`ZipFile.infolist`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.infolist) or [`ZipFile.namelist`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.namelist), and transfer them in-memory to the SFTP server using [`ZipFile.open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.open) and [`SFTPClient.putfo`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.putfo):

```
for i in root.infolist():
    with root.open(i) as f:
        to_sftp.putfo(f, "/remote/path/" + i.filename)
```

*(untested, just a concept)*

---

Alternatively, if you have a shell access to the server, run `unzip` (or an equivalent) directly on the server, to avoid a need to download the ZIP file and upload back the extracted files.

---

Note that it might be more efficient to read the ZIP archive directly from the SFTP server:

```
with to_sftp.open('<dir name/filename.zip', bufsize=32768) as f:
    root = z.ZipFile(f, 'r')
```

*I also assume the `r` mode is more appropriate for your task.*
*For the purpose of the `bufsize=32768`, see [Reading file opened with Python Paramiko SFTPClient.open method is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58433996/850848)*.