# How to upload all files from Windows folder to SFTP folder in Python

Tags: python, sftp, pysftp

I am trying to upload all the files in my Windows folder to SFTP folder. Below is my code. If there are no files in csv folder, nothing should happen. How to achieve this?

```
with pysftp.Connection(host, username, password) as sftp:
    localpath = r'files\csv'
    remotepath = '/2021/November'
    sftp.put(localpath,remotepath)
```

It throws the below error for now.

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'files\csv'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Connection.put` can upload a single file only.

To upload all files in a folder, you can use [`Connection.put_d`](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pysftp.html#pysftp.Connection.put_d). For a recursive upload, you can use [`Connection.put_r`](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pysftp.html#pysftp.Connection.put_r). Unfortunately neither works on Windows.

But it's easy to implement a portable recursive upload, see:
[Python pysftp put_r does not work on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58460718/850848#58466685)

---

*Note that pysftp is dead project. Consider switching to Paramiko. See [pysftp vs. Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48434941/850848)*.